# updating table in bigquery

Tags: python, sql, python-2.7, google-bigquery

Is it possible to update a column in an existing table in bigquery using python client libraries? I have a column with all strings and I have changed the strings to numbers. I want this to be updated in the table. How do I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do it is to rewrite the entire table with SQL query [using `REPLACE`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#select-replace) clause.

```
#standardSQL
SELECT *, REPLACE (CAST(col) AS INT64 as col) FROM T
```